# Beginner Having trouble with Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I created the board as a list, then created a function to display it. The issue I am having is with my function. I am trying a counter with even/odd booleans to decide player turn and trying to use an acceptable list for indexing the replacement for inputing X or O into the list. I also have a line to verify user input and respond with an error message. I am not too far in but I was wondering if you could look at my code and spot whats wrong with it. When I run it I get the error message: `IOPub data rate exceeded`.

```
board= ['','','','','','','','','']
def show_game():
    print(board)
show_game()

def turn_input():
    turn= 0
    acceptable_index = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,]
    
    while turn%2==0:
        show_game()
        print('Input your position as an index')
        
        choice_index= 'WRONG'
        while choice_index in acceptable_index== False:
            choice_index=int(input('Player One, you are X and it is your turn, what index do you want to pick? '))
            if choice_index.isdigit()== False or choice_range in acceptable_index== False:
                print("Make sure your index is the interger between 0 and 9")
    turn+=1
        
    while turn%2!=0:
        show_game()
        print('Input your position as an index')
        
        choice_index= "wrong"
        while choice_index in acceptable_index== False :
            choice_index=int(input('Player Two, you are O and it is your turn, what position do you want to pick? '))
            if choice_index.isdigit()==False or choice_index in acceptable_index== False:
                print("Make sure your position is the interger between 0 and 9")
    turn+=1

turn_input()
```

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

Comment: Your `turn+=1` or some function/condition to change `turn` or to `break` needs to be within the while loop; otherwise, the while loop will never exit.

Comment: One quick comment: use `not`, not `==False`, as it is more readable and avoids potential ambiguities like `choice_index in acceptable_index== False` - here there is not a precedence issue, but `choice_index not in acceptable_index` avoids any head scratching.

Comment: BTW, the error means your code is in an infinite loop spewing output faster that the IO module can handle.

Comment: Where is `choice_range` defined?

Comment: Instead of `turn` variable, you can use `bool` variable and update it as: `firstPlayer = not firstPlayer`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow.

It looks like your while loops never terminate because your turn incrementation is outside the loop. Once you get a valid input, you can use `break` to exit the while loop.

I would also use an if statement for the outer loops and only increment the turn counter at the end of a turn.

For example:

```
if turn%2==0:
        show_game()
        print('Input your position as an index')
        
        choice_index= 'WRONG'
        while choice_index in acceptable_index== False:
            choice_index=int(input('Player One, you are X and it is your turn, what index do you want to pick? '))
            if choice_index.isdigit()== False or choice_range in acceptable_index== False:
                print("Make sure your index is the interger between 0 and 9")
            else:
                break
if turn%2!=0:
        show_game()
        print('Input your position as an index')
        
        choice_index= "wrong"
        while choice_index in acceptable_index== False :
            choice_index=int(input('Player Two, you are O and it is your turn, what position do you want to pick? '))
            if choice_index.isdigit()==False or choice_index in acceptable_index== False:
                print("Make sure your position is the interger between 0 and 9")
            else:
                break
turn+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because your `turn += 1` is outside of the `while` loop which is causing your while loop to continuously loop forever.

I went a step further beyond just fixing that.  I also removed a lot of duplicate code and fixed your input loop for when the user selects the wrong index.  All that is left for you to do is figure out how to determine the winner and the end of the game.

You also might want to output a separate error message for when the user inputs an index that has already been chosen.  I already checked for the condition but it doesn't have a specific error message.

```
board= ['','','','','','','','','']
def show_game():
    print(board)

def turn_input():
    turn= 0
    players = ["X", "O"]
    names = ["Player One", "Player Two"]
    acceptable_index = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    winner = False
    while not winner:
        show_game()
        current = turn % 2
        print('Input your position as an index')
        while True:
            choice_index=input(f'{names[current]}, you are {players[current]}, and it is your turn, what index do you want to pick? ')
            if choice_index.isdigit():
                digit = int(choice_index)
                if digit in acceptable_index:
                    if board[digit] == '':
                        board[digit] = players[current]
                        break
            print("Make sure your index is the interger between 0 and 9")
        turn+=1

turn_input()
```